# Image/text opacity gradient to transparent

Tags: css, image, text, gradient, opacity

Ive found almost what I am looking for on here but not totally. Ive seen gradients added to images that are colours, but im looking to fade an image out to 0% opacity.
In addition, in this possible to do to text also? To get an effect like this?[image]

Answer (score 4):

This may helps you [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/f4gxs/)
i just added a layer have some opacity changing from top to bottom.

**HTML**

```
<div id="layer"></div>
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum         has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.

It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).


Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes from a line in section 1.10.32.

The standard chunk of Lorem Ipsum used since the 1500s is reproduced below for those interested. Sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 from "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" by Cicero are also reproduced in their exact original form, accompanied by English versions from the 1914 translation by H. Rackham.
```

**CSS**

```
#layer{
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(
                           linear, left top, left bottom, 
                           from(rgba(255,255,255,0.1)),
                           to(rgba(255,255,255,0.8)),
                           color-stop(.9,#fff)
                       );
    position         : fixed;
    width            : 100%;
    height           : 100%;
}
```

Comment: i did update your fiddle with rgular gradient syntax and pointer-events, so links, form, text can be reached :) http://jsfiddle.net/f4gxs/1/

Answer (score 2):

You can use **inset box-shadows** on a pseudo element.

The pseudo element is positioned over the text so that it's inset box-shadow covers the text and fades it out to 0%. You need to add `pointer-events:none;` on the pseudo element if you have interactive content (like links) in the div.

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/4AMP7/)**

*HTML :*

```
<div> ... CONTENT ...</div>
```

*CSS :*

```
div{
    position:relative;
}
div:after{
    content:'';
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px -300px 200px -100px #fff;
    box-shadow: inset 0px -300px 200px -100px #fff;
    pointer-events:none;
}
```

Comment: That looks good! So you've created an inset shadow of white, yes? Which has the same effect?
And i assume a similar approach can be used to do this on images as well?

Comment: @DSHEP on image , it won't work because it doesn't generate pseudo-elements. :) (hello at web-tiki)

Comment: @DSHEP you can use exaclty the same aproach with an image, but you will need to wrap the image in a div and put the pseudo element on that div. like this http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/4AMP7/2/ (hey GCyrillus)

Comment: Ok... How can i do this with images also?